# What is the proper configuration required to connect to oracle db via SSIS package from SQL Server 2019

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2019

I have SQL Server 2019 and ODBC provider 17 version 17.5.

But when I try to connect to Oracle using a connection string in SSIS package, it throws this error:

> The requested OLE DB provider OraOLEDB.Oracle.1 is not registered. If the 64-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 32-bit mode.
>
> Error code: 0x00000000. An OLE DB record is available.
>
> Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"
> Hresult: 0x80040154
> Description: "Class not registered".

Tried changing target from 64 to 32 and vice versa but does not work.

Also got this issue:

> An error occurred while setting the value of property "ConnectionString". The error returned is 0x80020009 "
> The connection string format is not valid. It must consist of one or more components of the form X=Y, separated by semicolons. This error occurs when a connection string with zero components is set on database connection manager.".

Comment: The second error says your connection string isn't correct. So what does it look like?

Comment: Its like below Data Source=ABC;User ID=viewer;Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Persist Security Info=True;

Comment: Can Someone help on this